# Как получить тип byte после операции int/int

Tags: java

Ситуация: нужно получить тип `byte` после операции `int/int`.
Если результат входит в диапазон `byte`, то вывести его, если не входит, то вывести сообщение-ошибку.
А так же обработать `Exception` при делении на `0` и `Exception` в принципе.
Как заставить такой кусок кода работать? Пробовал в 3 строке через `byte tempResult = (byte) (operand1 / operand2);`, но в итоге получал для последнего вызова не то, что нужно.

```
public byte divisionByte(int operand1, int operand2) {
    try {
        byte tempResult = operand1 / operand2;
        if (tempResult >= 127 && tempResult <= -128) {
            System.out.println("Результат не входит в диапазон Byte.");
        } else
            System.out.println(operand1 + " / " + operand2 + " = " + tempResult);
        return tempResult;
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println(operand1 + " / " + operand2 + " = We can't divide by 0. " + e + ". Shame on you!");
        return 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR " + e);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

В `Main` классе один вызов должен отдать значение, второй сообщение об ошибке при делении на `0`, третий что `"Результат не входит в диапазон Byte"`

```
calc.divisionByte(2, 2);
calc.divisionByte(2, 0);
calc.divisionByte(1000, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны делить в `int`, проверять диапазон, и только затем преобразовывать к `byte`. Если вы сразу преобразовываете к `byte`, то, например, значение 257 молча превратится в 1, и результат будет неправильным. В вашем коде условие `tempResult >= 127 && tempResult <= -128` никогда не нарушится, потому что тип `tempResult` уже `byte`!

Поменяйте тип `tempResult` на `int`.

---

Правильным дизайном для такой функции было бы сообщать о проблемах разными типами исключений. Писать на консоль в функции деления — очень плохо. Возможно, пользователь функции вовсе не использует её в консольном приложении. Или приложение-то консольное, но он вывел что-то на консоль до вызова функции, и рассчитывает вывести что-то после.